Polynomial inequality on a circle
Let $P(z)$ be a complex polynomial. Does the following inequality hold for points $z_1$ and $z_2$ on the unit circle:
$$ |P(z_1)-P(z_2)| \leq \max_{|z|=1} |P'(z)| \times |z_1-z_2| $$
where $P'(z)$ denotes the derivative?
Additional Context:
This inequality takes cue from the Real-Valued Lagrange Mean Value Theorem for differentiable functions on an interval. Given a differentiable function $f$ on $[a,b]$, there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that:
$$ f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a) $$
The  inequality for complex polynomials seeks to explore a similar relationship between the difference in function values and the maximum derivative on the unit circle for polynomial.

Ps:I ma aware that an exact MVT may not hold for complex functions,but I am interested in knowing whether the above inequality holds neverthless gor polynomials

Please edit to add some attempts or thoughts: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/2236

@aschepler ,I have added context and motivation

Is there a reason why you restrict to polynomials?

Hint #1: The unit disk is convex. Hint #2: Maximum modulus principle.

I am sorry ,I did not get it.The max indeed occurs on the circle,but how does that help @MartinR

Are you aware that $|P(z_1)-P(z_2)|/|z_1-z_2|$ can be estimated above by the maximum of $|P'(z)|$ on the line segment joining $z_1$ and $z_2$?

No ,I am sorry I am not.Could you kindly briefly explain why?@MartinR I would be obliged

See this answer.
